# AuthSub Token not working for new YouTube accounts

Tags: youtube-api

Is anyone else seeing the following issue?

- For older youtube accounts we can request an AuthSub token and upload to those accounts no problem.
- For new youtube accounts we can request an AuthSub token, but when we try to upload to that account we get an 'Unauthorized' error

We are planning to eventually migrate to OAuth 2.0, but I'd like to know if this is a known issue

Comment: After some more testing. I'm getting NoLinkedYouTubeAccount when trying to list the videos in that account. I know the account is lined to YouTube but the API seems to disagree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Answering this incase anyone wanders here*

Okay I'll file this under 'what the heck'

Turns out even if you load youtube and are signed in via your google ID.... you might not have a youtube account. I had to load 'http://www.youtube.com/create_channel' to create a channel/username to be able to make these API calls.

Why the heck does the login screen return an AuthSub token when the user has no account?!? As far as my user was concerned it looked like they have an account. YouTube loaded with their e-mail at the top and looks like a valid youtube login!

Thanks,
B.

Comment: There's some background at http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/10/introducing-google-account-support-and.html